# how I can access variable button:contains with class css phpUnit symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow" type="submit" ng-click="submitForm($event)">

<span class="visible-xs glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span>

<span class="hidden-xs">Rechercher</span>
</button>
```

class : 
the problem : $crawler->selectButton('.btn btn-lg btn-yellow') doesn't exist 
how I can access this variable ?
because I don't have a Id or name

```
  private $client;

protected function setUp()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $this->client = $client;
}


    public function testForm()
{

    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/test');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('.btn btn-lg btn-yellow')->form();

    $form->setValues(
        array(
            'form[search[searchName]]' => 'nom',
            //'form[search]' => 'search'
        )
    );

    $this->client->submit($form);
```

Comment: try with simple filter method as `$crawler->filter('.btn btn-lg btn-yellow')->form();`

Comment: InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your current approach: First `selectLink()` does not work with arbitrary CSS selectors. Also separating class names with spaces does not mean that the desired element has all class names (your selector would filter for a `btn-yellow` element inside a `btn-lg` element inside an element having the class `.btn`).

If you want to filter for an element with multiple classes you would have to do that like this: `$crawler->filter('.btn.btn-lg.btn-yellow')`

Comment: the problem is always the same : 
 
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty